# Error: SDK "iphonesimulator9.0" Cannot be located

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator, xcode7, xcodebuild

I recently updated Xcode to 7.1 And downloaded iOS 8.4 And iOS 9.0 Simulator.

When I run

```sh
xcodebuild -showsdks
```

I get

```sh
OS X SDKs:  OS X 10.11                      -sdk macosx10.11

iOS SDKs:   iOS 9.1                         -sdk iphoneos9.1

iOS Simulator SDKs:     Simulator - iOS 9.1             -sdk
iphonesimulator9.1

tvOS SDKs:  tvOS 9.0                        -sdk appletvos9.0

tvOS Simulator SDKs:    Simulator - tvOS 9.0            -sdk
appletvsimulator9.0

watchOS SDKs:   watchOS 2.0                     -sdk watchos2.0

watchOS Simulator SDKs:     Simulator - watchOS 2.0         -sdk
watchsimulator2.0
```

I want

`iOS Simulator SDKs:`

to point to the

`iOS 9.0 Simulator` or `8.4 Simulator`

instead of

`Simulator - iOS 9.1 -sdk iphonesimulator9.1`

I've tried

```sh
xcodebuild -sdk iphonesimulator9.0
```

But I get

```sh
xcodebuild: error: SDK "iphonesimulator9.0" cannot be located.
```

Comment: Legacy Simulator SDKs no longer ship with the latest version of Xcode.

Comment: Thanks @JAL - any clue how to install older SDKs?

Comment: Pull the SDKs from older versions of Xcode.  Take `Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk` from say Xcode 6.4 and rename it iPhoneSimulator8.4.sdk.

Comment: Thanks @JAL - Looks like that did the trick.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Legacy iOS Simulator SDKs no longer ship with the latest versions of Xcode.  To install an older Simulator SDK, take the `iPhoneSimulator.sdk` directory from an older version of Xcode (`Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/‌​iPhoneSimulator.sdk`), and copy it to your newer version.

For example, Xcode 6.4 comes with the 8.4 iOS Simulator SDK.  To install that in Xcode 7, take the directory:

```
Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk
```

Rename it from `iPhoneSimulator.sdk` to `iPhoneSimulator8.4.sdk`.

Copy it to your Xcode 7 Simulator SDK directory:

```
Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs
```

Observe your new Simulator SDKs:

[image: terminal]

Comment: Your console window 