# I get "xcrun: error: SDK "iphonesimulator" cannot be located" when running the toolchain

Tags: ios, xcode, kivy

I am trying to compile a Kivy program onto iOS, but when I run the command to build the Kivy distro I keep getting this error:

> xcrun: error: SDK "iphonesimulator" cannot be located

I have xcode on my computer.  What is going on?

Comment: This may help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33377837/error-sdk-iphonesimulator9-0-cannot-be-located

Comment: what is the command that you run?

Answer (score 36):

A bit late, but I had the same error experimenting with kivy and this helped me: 
Open in XCode *Preferences*, tab into *Locations* and take a look at your *Command Line Tools* selection. Mine was empty. When I changed it to the current used version suddenly the error was gone. I found this solution here (bottom): https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/rubymotion/Xw8gPcr2Fl8

If there is still something missing you can try to download an older IOS version to be sure there is something installed. Next to your appname you can select the device, click on it and select Download Simulations... and select the IOS you wish. I have done this step before the above, so I don't know if it's necessary.

Comment: Worked to fix issue with building on iOS with kotlin multiplatform, command line tools were not selected where you mentioned.

Answer (score 22):

```sh
sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/
```

reason: if you download the xcode more than one version . the path is not only one....

Answer (score 1):

It fixed for me once I downloaded the previous version of the simulator in my local.